# MySql query to check string with %

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two tables i.e. `queues` and `indexqueuemaps`.

Table **queses**:

- Qid
- Name

Table **indexqueuemaps**

- PhysicalQueueId
- ConditionFieldValue

Datafrom `queses`

```
Id     Name
1      Pricing
2      Return
3      EDI
```

Datafrom `indexqueuemaps`

```
PhysicalQueueId      ConditionFieldValue
1                    Member not on file.
2                    Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 17 long and the Max Length is 8
3                    Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 0001008077. Data is % long and the Max Length is 9
```

This is my query

```
SELECT `Name` FROM queues WHERE Id  IN 
(SELECT PhysicalQueueId FROM indexqueuemaps 
WHERE ConditionFieldValue = 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 17 long and the Max Length is 8');
```

When I run this query it return me **Name** = `Return`. What I want to do here is if I check `CoditionFieldValue = Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long and the Max Length is 8`

**instead of**

`Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 17 long and the Max Length is 8`

When I run the query it doesn't return any value because there is no any ConditionFieldValue is there in table. What I want to check is if such condition occurs and if there is `Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 0001008077. Data is % long and the Max Length is 9` this value in table query should return `EDI`

Suppose my query is

```
SELECT `Name` FROM queues WHERE Id  IN 
(SELECT PhysicalQueueId FROM indexqueuemaps 
WHERE ConditionFieldValue = 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long and the Max Length is 8');
```

The result of query should be **Name** = `EDI`

How can I implement this?

### EDIT

I have tried this query :

```
Set @msg = 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long and the Max Length is 8';
```

`SELECT q.`Name`FROM queues q inner join indexqueuemaps iq on q.Id = iq.PhysicalQueueId 
 WHERE 
 (iq.ConditionFieldValue = @msg) OR 
 (iq.ConditionFieldValue != @msg AND @msg like 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is %' 
 and iq.ConditionFieldValue like '% long and the Max Length is 8');`

in this query I am checking

> @msg like 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is %' 
>    and iq.ConditionFieldValue like '% long and the Max Length is 8'

I am checking it with hard coded string. But I want to check it with match value from table which contains text **before %** and **after %**. Simple I want to split the string from **ConditionFieldValue**  column which contains **%** symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a join between the two tables on the Id and PhysicalQueueId columns.

```
SELECT q.`Name` FROM queues q inner join indexqueuemaps iq on q.Id = iq.PhysicalQueueId 
WHERE 
(iq.ConditionFieldValue = @msg) OR 
(iq.ConditionFieldValue != @msg AND @msg like 'Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is %' 
and @msg like '% long and the Max Length is 8')
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But in table there is no such kind of value `Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long`

Comment: `Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long` this value is not in table. When such case occurs I want to check `Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 0001008077. Data is % long and the Max Length is 9` and return EDI as result

Comment: I do not understand your requirements, sorry. "Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long and the Max Length is 8" is in your indexqueuemaps table above

Comment: No I don't have any such kind of value in my table. check my table `indexqueuemaps` data

Comment: please check my answer again. It has been edited to have the value "Data is too long for MC/400 Field in XML Element: 20111109-20111113. Data is 171 long and the Max Length is 8" which is clearly in your table in your original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66729/discussion-between-ajay-punekar-and-adrian-nasui).

Comment: Hello, I want to do some changes in query. Please check my question edit.Thanks

Comment: use charindex and substring in sql for your need. I cannot help right now, very busy at work.